# Why do these share buttons not work in a Firefox?

Tags: javascript, firefox, sharing, social-media

I have a set of share buttons which work in Safari, Chrome and Opera but not Firefox. They just open a new blank window in Firefox why would that be?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function fbCurrentPage()
{window.open("https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u="+escape(window.location.href)+"&t="+document.title, '', 
'menubar=no,toolbar=no,resizable=yes,scrollbars=yes,height=300,width=600');}
function twitterCurrentPage()
{window.open("https://twitter.com/share?u="+escape(window.location.href)+"&t="+document.title, '', 
'menubar=no,toolbar=no,resizable=yes,scrollbars=yes,height=300,width=600');}
function gplusCurrentPage()
{window.open("https://plus.google.com/share?url="+escape(window.location.href)+"&t="+document.title, '', 
'menubar=no,toolbar=no,resizable=yes,scrollbars=yes,height=605,width=400');}
</script>

<div class="social">
<a href="javascript:fbCurrentPage()" class="facebook">Facebook</a>
<a href="javascript:twitterCurrentPage()" class="twitter">Twitter</a>
<a href="javascript:gplusCurrentPage()" class="gplus">Google+</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firefox gets confused by the `target="_blank"` attribute. Firefox opens new tab with `about:blank` URL and tries to execute one of the functions, e.g. `fbCurrentPage` in the newly opened tab, but the function doesn't exist in the "blank" document.

Just remove the `target` attribute from links. It's not needed since the functions use `window.open` which opens a new window.

And on a side note, your code is invalid in terms of HTML 5 spec. You have buttons inside links. `a` elements per [spec](http://w3c.github.io/html/textlevel-semantics.html#the-a-element) are not allowed to contain [interactive content](http://w3c.github.io/html/dom.html#interactive-content).

Comment: Thanks! That works now, I've updated those bits above.